# Mysql 5.6.13 server instance/management kind of Homescreen not appearing instead of it a local instance with blackbackgroud appears

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-workbench, workbench

This is what I want with my installation of MySQL 5.6.13:

[image]

But instead this is what I got on installation of MySQL 5.6.13:

[image]

Comment: I'm perplexed someone really does ask this kind of question as it is obvious that this is a new version.

Comment: Any particular reason why you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: Yes...there is one reason and it's laughable, my account has been locked to post any question for unknown period of time so i was trying to delete this question, and many other things to get my account the privilege to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second screenshot shows the [new MySQL Workbench interface](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new.html), which appeared in around June 2013 with the release of MySQL Workbench 6.0 and is presented [here](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2013/06/mysql-workbench-6-0-home-screen/). In order to get back the old interface, you need to downgrade MySQL Workbench 6.0 to MySQL Workbench 5.2. You can download the latter [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/5.2.html).